# Ruby on Rails - Avoiding Global Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Rails application where I use some global variables to show some results on a page based on dates. The date range variables are global. Now the problem is when the application is accessed by more than one person simultaneously, the global variables are shared and and not unique for each instance of the application.

Can someone point me to a good direction of handling variables for each instance of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of globals (which you should literally never use), you should use instance variables. Here they are set for finding orders in a date range

```
class OrdersController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    @start_date = params[:start_date] || 30.days.ago
    @end_date   = params[:end_date] || 30.days.ago
    @orders =  Order.where("start_date >= ?", @start_date).where("end_date <= ?", @end_date)
  end
end
```

note: literally every example you'll find on the web will use the above style and won't use ruby global variables.