# Using Global Variables vs Instance Variables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails application where I display some results based on a date range. I am using some global variables to set the dates. My code looks like below:

```
#index.html.erb 

  <td>From: <%= $from %></td>
  <td>To: <%= $to - 1.day%></td>


#controller

if (params[:first] || params[:next] || params[:previous])
    if params[:first]
        $from = Date.today - 7.day
        $to = Date.today + 1.day
    end

    if params[:next]
        $from = $from - 7.day
        $to = $to - 7.day
    end 

    if params[:previous]
        if $to != Date.today + 1.day
             $to = $to + 7.day
             $from = $from + 7.day
        end
    end 
end
```

This code seems to work fine, but when I access the application from more than one machine, it is a mess as the global variables are not unique for each instance I guess.

So I tried to use @variable (instance variables) instead of global variables. But whenever I submit the page from the view, all the variables get reset to NULL and the values don't persist to the controller. Can someone suggest me some pointers to deal with the problem here.

Comment: How are you 'submitting the view'?

Comment: @ramblex : That's my last option....:(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails - Avoiding Global Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669934/ruby-on-rails-avoiding-global-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more context it's unclear what your specific problem is. That said:

Controllers are instantiated *per request*: instance variables are obviously reset between requests.

Perhaps a `before_filter` and/or some utility methods to instantiate those `from`/`to` vars?

Also, the wrapper around each param's `if` statements seems redundant; is it really necessary?